# Return List of T where T is one of x classes (where x is greater than zero)

Tags: c#, .net

Please see the two classes below:

```
public class Person
    {
        int ID;
        string Name;
        string Address;
    }

    public class PersonModel
    {
        int ID;
        string Name;
        string Address;
    }
```

I am trying to create a function that will return a List of PersonModel or a List of Person depending what parameter is passed to the class:

Here is the client side function:

```
public static List<T> BuildList<T>()
        {
            //Populate list of T where T is wither a Person or PersonModel.
            //Return List of T
        }
```

Can this be done?

Comment: Why do you need two identical classes with different names?

Comment: Question is not very clear without information about how you actually populate those lists

Comment: "Can this be done?" - Yes, you can. Proposed function is ok. But the question is - is it what you really need?

Comment: @Roma Doskoch, one class is in the client layer and the other is in the business layer (seaparated by a web service).

Comment: Have you tried looking into the `where` keyword? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint

Comment: @w0051977, if client side function has acces to `Person` and `PersonModel` types why don't use only one type? 
Also, you can use `typeof` to determine type or convert to one type only or use base class or interface.

Comment: If you have separate classes for separate purpose (model, vs database entity) then its not clear why you need one generic method to "Build a list". Sounds more like the backend would build the list of entities, and somewhere you map to your models.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question in the conditions it has been asked. Yes, it is possible, and you nearly gave the answer yourself. You just need to initialize your list in your function with the template type, and then to fill it the way you need.

```
public static List<T> BuildList<T>() where T : new()
{
    List<T> ownList = new List<T>();

    // Populate your list the way you want.

    return ownList;
}
```

To populate your list, you can either create default class objets and add them to your list, like this:

```
T myObject = new T();
ownList.Add(myObject);
```

Or if you want to fill your list in a specific way depending on the type of T, you can use `typeof`.

```
if(typeof(T) == typeof(Person))
{
    // Initialize your Person objets in a specific way.
}
```

But I would avoid going for this option. I would either go for a specific declaration of your function for each one of your classes, or to use an interface which would reunite the elements of each one of your classes, make those classes implement this interface, and initialize your objects through your interface. Evk's answer is a good example of such an implementation.

Comment: If you want to do `T myObject = new T();` you'll need a `new()` constraint on the method

Answer (score 1):

You can introduce an interface which will share common properties of those two classes, then restrict your `T` parameter to this interface:

```
public interface IPerson {
    int ID { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Address { get; set; }
}

public class Person : IPerson {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

public class PersonModel : IPerson {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

public static List<T> BuildList<T>() where T : IPerson, new() {
    var result = new List<T>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        result.Add(new T() {
            ID = i,
            Address = "address" + i
        });
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: aaaaaaaand then you even have 3 same entities ;) Not to blame your answer. Just to point out that the question kinda smells

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case I'd say your question smells, I mean it looks like you're just looking in the wrong direction.

So I agree with @Jamiec comment:

> If you have separate classes for separate purpose (model, vs database entity) then its not clear why you need one generic method to "Build a list".

---

To answer the question in the title, here's the code (but doing this way is just weird):

```
public interface IPerson 
{
    public int Id {get;}
    public string Name {get;}
}

public GoodPerson : IPerson
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int GoodDeedCount {get; set;}


    void SayGoodDay(IPerson toPerson)
    {
        GoodDeedCount++;
        return $"Good day, {toPerson.Name}! :)"
    }
}

public BadPerson : IPerson
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Badness {get; set;}

    void SayShutUp(IPerson toPerson)
    {
        Badness++;
        return $"Shut up, {toPerson.Name}!"
    }
}

public UglyPerson : IPerson
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

    void SayNothing() { }
}

public static List<T> BuildList<T>()
    where T: new()
{
    var result = new List<T>();
    if (T is GoodPeson)
    {
         result.Add(new GoodPerson{Id = 1, Name = "Pinky", GoodDeedCount = 0});
         result.Add(new GoodPerson{Id = 2, Name = "Brain", GoodDeedCount = 0});
    }
    else if (T is BadPerson)
    {
         result.Add(new BadPerson{Id = 1, Name = "Sunshine", Badness = 0});
    }
    else if (T is UglyPerson)
    {
         result.Add(new UglyPerson{Id = 1, Name = "No", Badness = 0});
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Interface and implement that in the both class then use that interface in generic method as well

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

    }

    public static List<T> BuildList<T>() where T : IPersonModel, new()
    {
        //Populate list of T where T is wither a Person or PersonModel.
        //Return List of T
        // Implement here with any loop
        return null;// you need to return any value
    }
}


public interface IPersonModel
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Address { get; set; }
}
public class Person : IPersonModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

public class PersonModel : IPersonModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```